# Del libro: El lenguaje de programación C, de Dennis M. Ritchie y Brian W. Kernighan

Tags: c, bucles, caracteres, linux-mint

Tengo un problema con la forma en cómo utilizar EOF.
En el primer capítulo de este libro los autores usan EOF para terminar de procesar un texto, pero cuando yo programa sus ejercicios (1.9 en este caso: Escriba un programa que copie su entrada a la salida, reemplazando cada cadena de uno o más  blancos por un sólo blanco) no sé como utilizar ese botón o botones, o cuál sea. Tengo una distribución Linux Mint, por si en algo puede ayudar.
Me dijeron que con Ctrl + C, pero ese corta de tajo el programa y ya no me muestra el resultado . También me pasa lo mismo con Ctrl + Z. Usé el símbolo '|'para acabar de introducir texto, pero no es lo conveniente. Alguien me podría ayudar a saber cómo remediarlo. Hice este pequeño código para ejemplificar:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*Este programa imprime todas las palabras con un solo espacio entre ellas*/

int main ()
{
    int c, d;
    while((c = getchar()) != '|')  // En vez de | debería ir EOF
    {
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\t')  //Si encuentra un espacio, verificsrá si se escriben más espacios sucesivos.
        {
            while((d = getchar()) == ' ' || d == '\t')
                ;                        //Mientras haya espacios sucesivos irá leyendo caracteres
            putchar(c);                  //Imprime el primer espacio en blanco 
            putchar(d);                  //Imprime el primer caracter que no es espacio blanco después de una sucesión  de espacios en blanco 
        }
        else
            putchar(c);                 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Intenta con `Ctrl + D` eso debería mandar `EOF`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ese era el bueno

Comment: Por favor, pon en el título de la pregunta el problema _específico_ que tienes, y mueve al cuerpo el título actual, ya que no es relevante para el título en sí. No olvides además responder tu pregunta (en base a [answer]) y aceptarla cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10720881/13419694